# Pushing result from promise.all into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise, fetch

I'm struggling at the moment as the title would suggest with what I am trying to do. I have some sort of an idea what is happening, although I just can't get it to work 100% how I want to.

### My Problem

After all my promises has been solved I would like to return an Array with all the response data. However for some reason when I return pokemons outside the promise all I get is an empty array. However inside the promise as you see I get after the 5th time, the array I want with 5 objects. The interesting part is in my main function Pokegame, I also console log teamOne. I however get an empty array ("[]") but the the same properties as the console log "inside", however I cant access the keys in this one. I've tried different things but for some reason I just can't return a "normal" array from the function getPokemons.

### Code

```
import React from "react";
import Pokedex from "./Pokedex";
import Pokecard from "./Pokecard";

var PokeAPI = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

const getPokemonIDs = () => {
  var team = [];
  while (team.length < 5) {
    var randomPokemonID = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 807);
    team.push(randomPokemonID);
  }
  return team;
};

const getPokemons = () => {
  var pokemonIDs = getPokemonIDs();
  var pokemons = [];
  Promise.all(pokemonIDs).then(pokemonIDs => {
    for (let x in pokemonIDs) {
      fetch(PokeAPI + pokemonIDs[x])
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          pokemons.push(response);
          console.log("===inside===");
          console.log(pokemons);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  });
  console.log("==end==");
  console.log(pokemons.length);
  return pokemons;
};

const Pokegame = () => {
  const teamOne = getPokemons();
  console.log("==teamOne===")
  console.log(teamOne);

  return (
    <div>
      <Pokedex team={teamOne} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pokegame;
```

### Console Output

```
    ===inside===
    index.js:27 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    index.js:27 ==end==
    index.js:27 0

    ===teamOne===
    index.js:27 []
    0: {abilities: Array(2), base_experience: 63, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(0), height: 3, …}
    1: {abilities: Array(1), base_experience: 72, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(20), height: 6, …}
    2: {abilities: Array(3), base_experience: 175, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(9), height: 13, …}
    3: {abilities: Array(3), base_experience: 81, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(17), height: 5, …}
    4: {abilities: Array(2), base_experience: 238, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(4), height: 16, …}
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)

    index.js:27 ===inside===
    index.js:27 [{…}]

    index.js:27 ===inside===
    index.js:27 (2) [{…}, {…}]

    index.js:27 ===inside===
    index.js:27 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

    index.js:27 ===inside===
    index.js:27 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

    index.js:27 ===inside===
    index.js:27 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {abilities: Array(2), base_experience: 63, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(0), height: 3, …}
    1: {abilities: Array(1), base_experience: 72, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(20), height: 6, …}
    2: {abilities: Array(3), base_experience: 175, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(9), height: 13, …}
    3: {abilities: Array(3), base_experience: 81, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(17), height: 5, …}
    4: {abilities: Array(2), base_experience: 238, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(4), height: 16, …}
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

### Speculations

So I know that the promise will get put on the callback queue stack and that's why it returns an empty array the first time, however I do not understand why console log teamOne or even console log pokemons would log an empty array with like attributes?

### Code SandBox

[image: Edit competent-resonance-iq1h2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `Promise.all()` is that there are actually not any promises. `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises, while you are passing an array of IDs.
Try this (logging removed):

```js
Promise.all(
  pokemonIDs.map(id => {
    return fetch(PokeAPI + id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        pokemons.push(result);
      });
  })
).then(() => {
  console.log("==end==");
  console.log(pokemons.length);
  console.log(pokemons);
});
```

Forked sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-breeze-bozdm?file=/src/components/Pokegame.js (slightly edited to integrate with React).

Personally, I like to use `Promise.all()` to run parallel requests, but for other cases, I prefer `async` / `await` as it is very easy to write and read without too much extra thinking. The original example can then be rewritten like this (provided the parent function is async)

```js
await Promise.all(
  pokemonIDs.map(id => {
    return fetch(PokeAPI + id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        pokemons.push(result);
      });
  })
);

console.log("==end==");
console.log(pokemons.length);
console.log(pokemons);
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Lada said about the `Promise.all`, AFAIK, if you want to async update your model, you will need to use `useEffect` maybe `useState`

```js
import React from "react";
import Pokedex from "./Pokedex";
// import Pokecard from "./Pokecard";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

var PokeAPI = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

const getPokemonIDs = () => {
  var team = [];
  while (team.length < 5) {
    var randomPokemonID = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 807);
    team.push(randomPokemonID);
  }
  return team;
};

const getPokemons = () => {
  var pokemonIDs = getPokemonIDs();
  return Promise.all(
    pokemonIDs.map(pokemonId =>
      fetch(PokeAPI + pokemonId)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          console.log("===inside===");
          return response;
        })
    )
  );
};

const Pokegame = () => {
  const [teamOne, setTeamOne] = useState([]);

  console.log(teamOne);
  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons().then(team1 => {
      console.log(team1);
      setTeamOne(team1);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Pokedex team={teamOne} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pokegame;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sound-uoo6v?file=/src/components/Pokedex.js

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off of @láďa-durchánek answer you can further optimize the Promise.all call:

```js
async function getThemAll(pokemonIDs) {
  const pokemons = await Promise.all(
    pokemonIDs.map(async (id) => {
      const response = await fetch(id);
      return response.json();
    })
  );

  console.log("==end==");
  console.log(pokemons.length);
  console.log(pokemons);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

let array1 = [a, b, c]

let array2 = [b, c, d]

let combined = array1.push(...array2)